# NGINX - Redirect location from https to http (redirect loop)

Tags: http, nginx, redirect, https

Trying to redirect a location from https to http, getting a redirect loop in the browser.

P.S I've installed certbot (Let's Encrypt) to get the ssl certificate.

I've tried different server blocks, same server block, return 301, rewrite but nothing seems to do the trick.

```
server { 
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name example.com;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /update {
        return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot 
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I'd like to get https://example.com/update/ to redirect to http://example.com/update/

Comment: Your second `server` block just redirects `http` back to `https`. You need to decide how `http://example.com/update/` will be handled before you start redirecting to it.

Comment: Doesn't return end the file? Anyhow, I moved the second server block above the first, it made no difference. Pretty new to this, so I'm not fully aware on how to edit it in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figure you need to change this part.

```
server {
if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen   80;
server_name example.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

To only this.

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name example.com;
}
```

Edit:
So if it doesn't redirect anything to https at all after doing so, then I'm wrong. Let's try to add an exception of redirection for your /update path then, by adding a line like: location /update {} in the code below somewhere? If anyone can try to sneak in on this it'd  be awesome. I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it or not.

```
server {
if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen   80;
server_name example.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: But then it wont redirect anything to https at all?

Comment: I edited the answer with possibly a way to add an exception of redirection to https at the second server block. Not sure if this is the way to do it though or if it's even correct, perhaps someone else can confirm.